# Using manual login in django

Tags: django, redirect, authentication, django-authentication

I am following the [sample code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.login) on the django docs for the `auth` function `login()` for the purpose of learning about the various ways login can be achieved. I am aware of the [built-in forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.forms) and [built-in views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.views), and will ultimately end up using them, but I am trying to *understand*, not just to know.

The problem I'm having is that the user is logged in successfully in check_user, but doesn't seem to persist in the session when the redirect is called. Why is the is_authenticated() function giving me inconsistent results? I have a feeling it's to do with RequestContext, but I'm not sure what.

```
def check_user(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            test1 = user.is_authenticated() ### True
            test2 = request.user.is_authenticated() ### False
            return HttpResponseRedirect(NEXT_PAGE) ### NEXT_PAGE gives request.user.is_authenticated() is False
        else:
            return HttpResponse("disabled account")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("invalid login")
```

Comment: Check, do you have correct [INSTALLED_APPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#installation), [TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#authentication-data-in-templates), [MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#authentication-in-web-requests) in your settings.py

Comment: yes I have those settings correct according to the docs you linked. I didn't have TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS specified so I added it to be sure, however the issue still persists.

Comment: And you're sure you have 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware' in your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES ?

Comment: as per the standard startapp settings: MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (...'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',...) copied and pasted

Comment: You wrote `request.user.is_authenticated is False`. I suppose it is in template? If so, try to use `user.is_authenticated`. I.e. without `request.`, as written [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#id8). And be sure, `'django.core.context_processors.request'` and `'django.core.context_processors.auth',` are present in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.

Comment: adding 'django.core.context_processors.request' to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS seems to have fixed it. Not sure why this isn't mentioned in the docs, but glad to have it fixed. I will look into context processors more. Thanks stalk.